# Flex having a VBox with Vertical Buttons

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I am trying to get a left hand like panel bar in my application, one much like the OneNote left hand(notebook) panel.

I have been trying to use a VBox with Buttons and setting the rotation on the buttons to 90. The buttons seem to disappear when I do this.

An example of what I am trying to achieve is here: http://www.rid00z.net/panelBarExample.png

What is the best way to achieve Vertically stacked buttons like this?

Answer (score 0):

try putting all the buttons inside an Hbox and then setting the rotation of the Hbox to 90.

Oh and also make sure you [rotate around using a point at the center](http://www.joelconnett.com/flex-rotation-around-a-point.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom component to do it. I would make each "button" a canvas and display text in it vertically (embedding the font you want to use to do that) - the canvas would have a click event - I would use canvas over a standard Button because it allows more flexibility. In this new component you would have functions to add or delete buttons. I can clarify if it would help.